# Nuxt Loader - Throttle for Custom Loader

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, loader

I'm using a custom loader component for my project, and my nuxt config looks like this:

```
loading: '~/components/common/loading.vue'
```

The problem is that this component doesn't throttle a few milli-seconds and with every page change, this flickers and causes a bad user experience. Is there any way to add a throttle as we'd normally add for the default component like `throttle: 200` inside the `loading` object like,

```
loading: { throttle: 200 }
```

Since my loading option doesn't have an object, instead has a string/path to my custom loading component, I'm not sure what to do here.

Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading

Comment: Did you try to use `throttle` in the `loading.vue` component? Or maybe pasing `loading: { name: '~/components/common/loading.vue', throttle: 200 }` in the config?

Comment: Hi, these options didn't work unfortunately. Passing `loading: { name: '~/components/common/loading.vue', throttle: 200 }` resulted in the loader not being displayed at all, even with `throttle: 0` being set. And setting `throttle` inside `loading.vue` made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use a custom loading component using [Vuetify overlay component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overlays/) with a throttle:

```html
<template>
  <v-overlay :value="loading">
    <v-progress-circular
      indeterminate
      size="64"
    />
  </v-overlay>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    loading: false
  }),
  methods: {
    clear () {
      clearTimeout(this._throttle)
    },
    start () {
      this.clear()
      this._throttle = setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading = true
      }, 200)
    },
    finish () {
      this.clear()
      this.loading = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is inspired by the Nuxt [default loading component](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/2.x/packages/vue-app/template/components/nuxt-loading.vue).

Answer (score -1):

You could add a setTimeout within your `start()` method in your custom loader component `~/components/common/loading.vue`.

```js
methods: {
   start() {      
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading = true;
     }, 2000);           
   },
   finish() { ... }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. If `finish()` is called before the timeout expires, then the loader is shown forever.